# Why does java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.convert throw an AbstractMethodError instead of being abstract

Tags: java, enums, abstract

`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` has this source:

```
public long convert(long sourceDuration, TimeUnit sourceUnit) {
    throw new AbstractMethodError();
}
```

Why isn't this an `abstract` method like

```
abstract int excessNanos(long d, long m);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Single line comments above the method declaration says following,

```
// To maintain full signature compatibility with 1.5, and to improve the
// clarity of the generated javadoc (see 6287639: Abstract methods in
// enum classes should not be listed as abstract), method convert
// etc. are not declared abstract but otherwise act as abstract methods.
```

Here, [`6287639`](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6287639) is bug id which says,

> *JDK-6287639 : Abstract methods in enum classes should not be listed as abstract*

Now consider the following `enum` considering it as class and every enum constant as an `Object`, it is clear that if we create `Object` of something abstract we must provide implementation and to avoid this `convert` is not `abstract`,

```
enum Blocks {
    A1, B1, C1;
    // It will say enum constant must implement 
    // the abstract method test
    abstract int test();
}
```

Comment: thank you！ But some of this class(TimeUnit) is abstract, some are not